# Tridion 2013 Content Delivery File Encoding after migration from Tridion 2011

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery

We are migrating our Tridion platform from Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 to Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. The Content Delivery (Deployer, Web Service, etc...) is installed as a Java Web Application.

With Tridion 2011, we had to configure the Tomcat server with the following java parameter "**-Dfile.encoding=UTF8**" to make the deployer able to process UTF-8 encoded files during the publication (Chinese characters for ex).

But with Tridion 2013 SP1 it seems that the default encoding of Component Presentations in the Broker db has changed to UTF-16 (See [Component Presentations in SQL 2012 DB shows up as a different encoding with 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201/2968/#2968))

My question : Is this parameter still needed ? Do we have to update it to "UTF16" with Tridion 2013 SP1 ?

EDIT: Yes I know UTF8 is enough for Chinese or other languages. It was working well on our Tridion 2011 SP1 env and I know how to set the encoding on the publication target. My question is more linked to the migration it-self. When I have a look at CPs in the DB, "original" one's are still in a "readable" format. But those I've republished since Tridion 2013 migration are now in a "weird chinese like" format.

Ex :

> 挼湯整瑮ാ 㰠摉琾浣㠺ⴱ㌴㌷㰱䤯㹤਍†吼瑩敬䬾摩慚楮⁡畓数獲慴婲爠瑥牵獮琠⁯牢湩⁧畯⁴桴⁥瑳牡⁳湩琠敨氠瑩汴⁥湯獥⼼楔汴㹥਍†匼浵慭祲䐾扵楡‬䅕㭅䨠湡慵祲㈠ⰱ㈠㄰㨴䘠牯愠汬琠敨琠污湥整⁤档汩牤湥愠摮琠敨物瀠潲摵瀠牡湥獴漠瑵琠敨敲‬楋婤湡慩‬桴⁥睡牡ⵤ楷湮湩⁧档汩牤湥猧攠畤慴湩敭瑮挠湥牴ⱥ椠⁳景敦楲杮琠敨⁭⁡湵煩敵漠灰牯畴楮祴琠⁯

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chinese encoding issue in Broker](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13127/chinese-encoding-issue-in-broker)

Comment: i recently worked on Chinese and other characters, utf-8 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason for you to change this to UTF-16 since UTF-8 is working fine for your current application.
The default setting for UTF-16 is most probably to accommodate those few special characters which does not get fit in UTF-8.

So, if all characters in your exiting website are satisfied by UTF-8, there is no need to change this setting.

Comment: I'm concerned about the data migration from Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013. The storage of CPs has changed and republished Dynamic CPs seem to be stored in another encoding than original DCPs.

Comment: The API deals with this.